# Moment Timezone returning Uncaught TypeError on load

Tags: javascript, timezone, requirejs, typeerror, momentjs

I am working on implementing Moment Timezone into a Django application in order to correct for users accessing it from different time zones, and I am running into an error when importing the files through Require.js. moment.js, moment-timezone.js, and moment-timezone-data.js are all loading, but when my script runs and tries to initiate them, moment-timezone.js and moment-timezone-data.js throw Uncaught TypeErrors.

My moment-timezone-data.js file is copy-pasted from the [Moment.js timezone data generator](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) and looks like this (albeit with more time zones):

```
moment.tz.add({
    "zones": {
        "America/New_York": [
            "-4:56:2 - LMT 1883_10_18_12_3_58 -4:56:2",
            "-5 US E%sT 1920 -5",
            "-5 NYC E%sT 1942 -5",
            "-5 US E%sT 1946 -5",
            "-5 NYC E%sT 1967 -5",
            "-5 US E%sT"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "US": [
            "1918 1919 2 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1918 1919 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1942 1942 1 9 7 2 0 1 W",
            "1945 1945 7 14 7 23 1 1 P",
            "1945 1945 8 30 7 2 0 0 S",
            "1967 2006 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1967 1973 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1974 1974 0 6 7 2 0 1 D",
            "1975 1975 1 23 7 2 0 1 D",
            "1976 1986 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1987 2006 3 1 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2007 9999 2 8 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2007 9999 10 1 0 2 0 0 S"
        ],
        "NYC": [
            "1920 1920 2 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1920 1920 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1921 1966 3 0 8 2 0 1 D",
            "1921 1954 8 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "1955 1966 9 0 8 2 0 0 S"
        ]
    },
    "links": {}
});
```

The requireConfig file is set up like so:

```
require = {
    paths: {
        "moment": ServerInfo.generateStaticPathFor("js/ext/moment/moment-with-langs"),
        "moment-timezone": ServerInfo.generateStaticPathFor("js/ext/moment/moment-timezone"),
        "moment-timezone-data": ServerInfo.generateStaticPathFor("js/ext/moment/moment-timezone-data")
    },
    shim: {
        "moment-timezone-data": {
            "deps": ["moment-timezone"]
        }
    }
};
```

I then try to initiate Moment Timezone like so:

```
define(["moment", "moment-timezone", "moment-timezone-data"], function(moment) {
    var thisMoment = moment().tz('America/New_York').startOf('day');
});
```

moment-timezone-data.js throws an Uncaught TypeError of "Cannot call method 'add' of undefined" on line 1:

```
moment.tz.add({ ... });
```

moment-timezone.js throws an Uncaught TypeError of "Cannot call method 'rule' of undefined" on line 308:

```
return [zone, zone.rule(mom, lastZone)];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `define()` call only needs `moment-timezone` and `moment-timezone-data`. Essentially, `moment-timezone` acts like a drop-in replacement for `moment`, extending it to provide `.tz()`. Refer to [the example](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/):

```
define(["moment-timezone", "moment-timezone-data"], function (moment) {
    moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
});
```

Also, you don't need to shim the timezone data. Instead, just select the "AMD" option when using [the timezone data builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/).

Comment: I think the AMD option is largely what did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: So did here.. after 12 weeks and just before ditching moment js. select "AMD" did work

Answer (score 1):

Does it make any difference if you switch the dependency order?  I believe moment-timezone depends on moment-timezone-data, not the other way around.  But I'm not sure if it matters here or not.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this error when I made a typo in the timezone.

eg. `moment().tz("America/Los_Anegles").format();`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem when using the minified version of moment-timezone.js under [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.0.6/moment-timezone.min.js).
Just changed to the full source downloaded from [moment timezone website](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) and worked!

```
(function($) {
   moment.tz.add({
    "zones": {
        "America/Mexico_City": [
            "-6:36:36 - LMT 1922_0_1_0_23_24 -6:36:36",
            "-7 - MST 1927_5_10_23 -7",
            "-6 - CST 1930_10_15 -6",
            "-7 - MST 1931_4_1_23 -7",
            "-6 - CST 1931_9 -6",
            "-7 - MST 1932_3_1 -7",
            "-6 Mexico C%sT 2001_8_30_02 -5",
            "-6 - CST 2002_1_20 -6",
            "-6 Mexico C%sT"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "Mexico": [
            "1939 1939 1 5 7 0 0 1 D",
            "1939 1939 5 25 7 0 0 0 S",
            "1940 1940 11 9 7 0 0 1 D",
            "1941 1941 3 1 7 0 0 0 S",
            "1943 1943 11 16 7 0 0 1 W",
            "1944 1944 4 1 7 0 0 0 S",
            "1950 1950 1 12 7 0 0 1 D",
            "1950 1950 6 30 7 0 0 0 S",
            "1996 2000 3 1 0 2 0 1 D",
            "1996 2000 9 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "2001 2001 4 1 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2001 2001 8 0 8 2 0 0 S",
            "2002 9999 3 1 0 2 0 1 D",
            "2002 9999 9 0 8 2 0 0 S"
        ]
      },
      "links": {}
    });
    console.log(moment().tz("America/Mexico_City").format());
})(jQuery);
```