# Moment locale plugin is not loading

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I'm using `Moment`, `Moment Locale` and `Moment Timezone` plug-ins to support Locale as well as time zone for [Bootstrap datetime calender](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) Plug-in.

I'm using `requireJs` and below is the content of my configuration file:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '.',
    paths: {
        'jQuery': '../path to jQuery plugin',
        'moment': '../path to moment js plugin',
        'momentLocale':'../path to moment locale js plugin',
        'momentTimeZone':'../path to moment timezone js plugin'
    },
    shim: {
        'moment': {
            deps: ['jQuery']
        },
        'momentLocale': {
            deps: ['moment']
        }
    }
});
```

I followed the [link](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/143), included locale also in shim and edited the timezone library with `moment` to `momentLocale` to support for calendar both *locale* and *time zone*.

I'm passing the locale values to method which returns default locale.
In my application, I do have a lot of language which are not supported by the moment js. To overcome this, I'm maintaining mapping table to return the language which is moment support. (for ex: If I'm selected af_NA as a region, it should return "af" as language. Here is the context switch case for locale values.....

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'moment',
    'momentLocale'],
    function(
        $,
        moment,
        momentLocale ) {
            getLocaleForCal: function(region) {
                switch(region): {
                    case "af_NA":
                    case "af_ZA":
                        return "af";
                    break;
                    default:
                        return "en";
                    break;
                }
             }
         };
      });
```

Here is the options that I'm passing to calendar

```
$(function() {
    var currentRegion = this.getLocaleForCal("af_NA");
    $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({
        locale: moment.locale(currentRegion)
    });
});
```

The locale is showing by default "en", instead of "af". As the moment locale is not loading due to that it's setting the value with "en".

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `momentTimeZone` should also be add in `shim` section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'tz' of undefined - Ember Moment Timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531167/cannot-read-property-tz-of-undefined-ember-moment-timezone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment Timezone returning Uncaught TypeError on load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912613/moment-timezone-returning-uncaught-typeerror-on-load)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just added new reference of the moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js [file](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js) and it works fine for me. So my suggestion would be add reference/require of this file before moment.js file.

Comment: Thanks hanmina, The point "Uncaught Type Error" has been fixed after that I'm having moment locale plug-in, which is not loading.